# Remove Duplicates within an array element in Powershell

Tags: arrays, powershell, element

How can I remove duplicate values within an array element in PowerShell?

For example:

```
$array[0] = C1 C1 C3 C3
$array[1] = C1 C1 C2 C2
```

How can I removed the duplicates in Powershell, so that I have:

```
$array[0] = C1 C3
$array[1] = C1 C2
```

I tried `$array[0] | Select -Unique` but it was not successful. Nothing changed. With `$array | Select - Unique` the duplicates are removed without considering the single array elements.

Anyone a good idea?

Comment: You should comma separate array elements when creating your array.

Comment: How is this array created? Are `C1 C1 C3 C3` different property values or is it a `string`?

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon It is a String. It gets these values from an excel file

Comment: @AdminOfThings Also if I comma seperate it, how can I remove duplicates in one array element?

Comment: If they are space separated elements in a string, then you can use `$array[0] -split ' ' | select -unique`.

Comment: You need a delimiter so you can convert each `string` into a `string[]`, I think this is what @AdminOfThings mean,then is easy to get unique values.

Comment: Exactly, agreed. You could in theory use `$array[0] -split '\s+' | select -Unique` but you would be removing **all** extra spaces and some elements of your `string` might have spaces... If that makes sense.

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon actually they are seperated by \n, but I will try it and write back if it worked

Comment: @AdminOfThings beat me to it first. That;s exactly what i would do and what i was gonna suggest. To "*update*" the array after you can assign it to the same index: `$array[0] = $array[0].Split(' ') | Select-Object -Unique`

Comment: @AbrahamZinala  Thanks for your help, I appreciate it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works perfect if you use spaces as delimiter however if your string should have had a space then it will be removed. Ideally, you could create your `$array` with a specific delimiter like `|` or `;` or `,` that's up to you.

```
$array=@(
    'C1 C1 C3 C3'
    'C1 C1 C2 C2'
    'C1 C2 C3 C4'
    'C1 C1 C2 C2'
    'C1 C2 C3 C3'
    'C1 C2 C2 C2'
)

for($i=0;$i -lt $array.Count;$i++)
{
    $array[$i] = ($array[$i] -split '\s+' | Select-Object -Unique) -join ' '
}

PS /> $array
C1 C3
C1 C2
C1 C2 C3 C4
C1 C2
C1 C2 C3
C1 C2
```

Comment: Thank yo, +1 from me, I was adding/removing LogonWorkstations in AD, the following splits them by comma, removes duplicates, and re-joins. `$LogonWorkstations = ($LogonWorkstations -split ',' | Select-Object -Unique) -join ','`